# Last (count) entries

Tags: numbers, synonyms

I am currently documenting a web interface. What would you recommend as a more friendly way of saying:

> This will display the last *n* entries.

Where *n* is the number they have entered. I've been trying without success to find a solution that is not too wordy, yet remains clear.

Comment: Why must your description of this information be more 'friendly'? Surely it is enough that it is clear and concise (as it currently is)?

Comment: It feels too mathematical, it isn't something I would say in normal speech, which is something I'd prefer, but I'm not if English has such a phrase.

Comment: Well, this subject matter isn't exactly the stuff of normal conversation, is it? If you want to lighten the tone, it might be better to do it in your introductory descriptions or general examples rather than in sections that focus on the technical details.

Comment: Changing *last* to *most recent* is marginally less technical, but not much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it really *friendly* and you are allowed to sound a little informal, you may use something like

> The number says how many of the latest entries you want to be displayed.

or

> The button displays last entries. Their amount is limited by the number you have entered.

Of course you may also replace *entries* by something less technical, such as *items*, *books*, *bottles of beer* or whatever else based on your application's domain.

Comment: Both of the rewrites you suggest are verbose and somewhat roundabout, and thus end up less clear than the original form.

Comment: @jwpat7: I agree with what you said - it's true for us technical guys. However, I think that for a common non-technical guy the sentence "This will display the last n entries" is less understandable. Considering the latter as more clear requires some training and brain manipulation :)